# Merge two arrays in ngFor

Tags: arrays, angular, merge

I have two array-a that I get from services:

```
handleProjectLoaded(project){

    this.projectService.getCodesByType( "Structure" ).subscribe( response => {

        this.structures = response;
    });

    this.projectService.getCodesByType( "Direction" ).subscribe( response => {

        this.lines = response;
    });
}
```

One array is in structures and second I get in lines. I have them in html separate and with ngFor showed.

```
<div class="div-width-button3">
    <select #lineSelect class="custom-select custom-select-project" style="flex-basis:49%" (change)="addDirection(directionSelect.value); directionSelect.selectedIndex = 0;">
        <option selected disabled value="">Add a direction</option>
        <option *ngFor="let direction of directions" [value]=direction.id
            [selected]="direction.id==directionSelect.value">{{direction.name}}</option>
    </select> 
    <select #structureSelect class="custom-select custom-select-project"  style="flex-basis:49%"
        (change)="addStructure(structureSelect.value); structureSelect.selectedIndex = 0;">
        <option selected disabled value="">Add a structure</option>
        <option *ngFor="let structure of structures" [value]=structure.id
            [selected]="structure.id==structureSelect.value">{{structure.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need solution to show these two arrays as one with one ngFor. Is there any way to merge them??

Comment: Use Observable.forkJoin

Comment: You could use a pipe on the ngfor passing in both arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not test it, but why not use concat?

`<option *ngFor="let line of lines.concat(structures)" [value]="line.id">{{ line.name }}</option>`

Answer (score 2):

```
handleProjectLoaded(project){

  this.projectService.getCodesByType( "Structure" )
    .concat(this.projectService.getCodesByType( "Line" ))
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.structuresAndLines = response;
    });

}
```

**=== Edit ===**

Actually I changed my mind because I think structuresAndLines in my previous example would be a 2d array. So please try this instead:

```
handleProjectLoaded(project){

  Observable.zip(
    this.projectService.getCodesByType( "Structure" ),
    this.projectService.getCodesByType( "Line" ),
    (structures, lines) => structures.concat(lines),
  )
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.structuresAndLines = response;
  });

}
```

Comment: I will try this as well, seems more fit for me in a long run. Thanks